# Angular 6 currency format without decimal point with INR symbol

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to show currency symbol and comma separated based on INR without decimal point in angular 6

```
₹50
₹5,000
₹50,000
₹5,00,000
₹5,00,00,000

{{ 12345.23 | currency:"INR":0 }}
{{ 12345.23 | currency:"₹":0 }}

{{ 12345.23 | currency:"INR" }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try as below:

```
{{ 12345.23 | currency: 'INR':'symbol':'1.0-0' }}
```

For further detail, please refer documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Comment: for this input ```50000000|currency: 'INR':'symbol':'1.0-0'```,
output shown ```₹50,000,000```
expected: ```₹5,00,00,000```